# Evaluating limit $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}{- \ln (1- \frac{a_n}{s_n})}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a_n= \sqrt{n},\, n \geq 1,$ and let $s_n= a_1+ a_2....+ a_n.$ Then how to find $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}{- \ln (1- \frac{a_n}{s_n})}\right)$$

Comment: Can you show that $a_n/s_n\to 0$?

Comment: Hello, to avoid your question getting downvoted and closed, you should edit and include your attempts. Paramanand Singh's hint is a very good start and 90% of the solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the future please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we need to show is that $\frac{a_n}{s_n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.  It is trivial to see that $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt k>n$ so that $\frac{a_n}{s_n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$.  So clearly $\frac{a_n}{s_n}\to 0$.

And inasmuch as $\frac{-x}{1-x}\le \log(1-x)\le -x$ we see that

$$\frac{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}{\frac{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}{1-\frac{a_n}{s_n}}}\le \frac{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}{-\log\left(1-\frac{a_n}{s_n}\right)}\le \frac{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}\tag1$$

Letting $n\to \infty$ in $(1)$ and applying the squeeze theorem we find that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}{-\log\left(1-\frac{a_n}{s_n}\right)}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stolz-Cesaro for the case $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{s_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{s_{n+1}-s_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\sqrt{i}-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{i}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}=0$$

Now you can use the standard limit:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=0$$ your limit: 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{a_n}{s_n}\right)}{-\frac{a_n}{s_n}}}=1$$